# Can't get intent filter to launch activity from a uri

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to figure out how to launch an activity in my app from a custom URI such as myapp://myuriactivity

I've read a lot about the intent and intent filters in the android references and also read several examples, but for some reason I can't get my simple test to work.  Below is my manifest file, can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?  With the below file, if I open the browser and try to navigate to http://org.test.launchtest it just says the page doesn't exist.  Shouldn't this work?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<activity android:name=".MyUriActivity">
        <intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
<data android:scheme="http" android:host="org.test.launchtest" />
```

Comment: Looks like it cut off my closing </intent-filter>, but it is there.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I wasn't able to do the trick with host too. Hence I ended up with using more specific scheme.

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
<data android:scheme="com.stackoverflow.example" />
</intent-filter>
```

Probably you may use scheme solution too?

Comment: How did you open that activity, by entering com.stackoverflow.example:// in the browser?  I tried this and again, nothing.  It just runs a query of the text.

Comment: I wasn't able to do the trick with manually entering an adsress in browser. But it works perfectly if you click a link with the scheme or starting an Intent manually providing Uri starting with the scheme.
At http://stack-examples.appspot.com/ you can see the example link which works for The Presidents app :) http://www.cyrket.com/p/android/com.socratica.mobile.presidents/ You can try installing the app and then clicking the link in browser.